# How do I make a docker container apear as a normal computer on the network and is this what a ipvlan network mode is?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-network

First off I am very new to this and theres probably a very easy solution but im just not searching the right things, so I appologise for that.

Basically what im trying to do is have a docker container apear like any other computer or device on my lan network (my house lan network aka the one right after the router not a lan inside of docker) ive put a little diagram below with what I THINK ipvlan does and if thats not correct how would I be able to do the same kind of thing?

If this is very easy and theres an article on how to do something like this a link to a page is ofcourse 100% a valid response.

Thanks a ton :D

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9cQK.jpg)

I havent had the chance to acctually try anything yet but I need it ready to be able to setup quickly since I only have a limited amount to set it up when I get access to the machine. Basically I have one or two shots two get this right and cant do much pre testing unfortunatly.

Comment: Using the `host` network, you can make your container visible to the outside via the machine (server/talptop/else) that hosts it. https://docs.docker.com/network/host/

Comment: A Docker container is a wrapper around a single process.  Normally, from an external networking point of view, you'd connect to that process the same way you would any other process.  For example you might connect to the host on port 5432 and it will reach a PostgreSQL server, and from externally you can't tell whether it's a container or not.  Why do you want to give a process its own network identity; how would you do this without Docker?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I know that but I am trying to make the container appear under a different IP address, do you know if this is possible?